# Is there a way to use firefox favicons with alt-tab?

Tags: gnome, firefox

At work, I tend to have multiple instances of firefox open at once -- one for outlook web app, one for jira, another one or two for some in-house web apps... on top of this, I will often have a few terminals (tmux helps keep this to a minimum). I am very habituated to use alt-tab to switch between applications.

The problem that I have is that when I'm switching using alt-tab, all instances of firefox use the firefox icon, so I can't tell at a glance which firefox I'm switching to... yes, there's some text there, but I don't want to stop and read while I'm flipping through icons. Is there a way for alt-tab to display the favicon (the icon that shows to the left of the URL in a web browser) of the page rather than the firefox icon?

Comment: whilst I appreciate you have removed the 10.04 tag - the alt-tab process is different in 12.04 and later compared to 10.04.  Thus any answer may not be applicable to your circumstance.  Since you are now asking for a 12.04 and later answer, please ensure you validate the answer with these supported versions of ubuntu.

Comment: Does the alt-tab behaviour change between the standard 12.04 and the Gnome flavour?

Answer (score 2):

**If you're using Ubuntu 11.10 or newer**, you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (the key to the left of <kbd>1</kbd> and below <kbd>Esc</kbd>), to switch between the windows of the same application.

It shows smaller resolution images of whatever is shown in the windows. Below is a sample screenshot:

[image: Ubuntu alt backtick screenshot]